# GIT создать локальную ветку на основе удаленной ветки

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Как сделать локальную веку А на основе удаленной ветки B?

Правильно ли я понимаю

```
git checkout -b A origin/B
```

Comment: А чем не подойдёт` git pull origin branchname`?